# Object cleanup with pointers

Tags: c++

Just want to know if the following is true, as I work towards a reset feature in a small game I'm working on.

So if I have a setup like so:

```
class Game {
public:
  Game(Ball b, Paddle one, Paddle two) : b(b), one(one), two(two) { }
  void initGame();
  void resetGame();
private:
  Ball b;
  Paddle one;
  Paddle two;
  std::vector<GameObject *> objects;
};

Game::initGame() {
  objects.push_back(&b);
  objects.push_back(&one);
  objects.push_back(&two);
}

Game::resetGame() {
  while (!objects.empty()) {
    objects.pop_back();
  }
  b = Ball();
  one = Paddle();
  two = Paddle();

  initGame();
}
```

My question is with the resetGame method. I empty out the array of pointers, and then replace the objects below. Now, given they were pointers to pieces of memory, and the original objects get replaced, does the original memory leak? Should i have deleted the data first? I know delete is used in conjunction with new, but I'm not sure if the compiler cleans this up for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not leaking memory because you're not using the `new` keyword.

Comment: The answer depends on what `Ball` and `Paddle` do in their constructors, and whether or not you have obeyed the Rule of Three or the Rule of Zero.

Comment: BTW, you may directly use `objects.clear()`.

Comment: @jxh how can it depend on `Ball` and `Paddle`? Those are local object allocated on the stack, so their destructor will be automatically called (of course the destructor has to do the "right" job). But the `pop_back` doesn't have anything to do with the destructor of the object, since the vector is made up of pointers not objects themselves.

Comment: @vsoftco: They are copy constructed in from the constructor of `Game`, and then assigned over in `resetGame`. Destructor is not good enough.

Comment: @jxh ok, but this is still a problem of the object themselves, not of how the vector deals with them. In any case, I agree with you that the rules of 5/3/0 have to be obeyed.

Comment: @vsoftco: He asked "the original objects get replaced, does the original memory leak?". The answer depends on what was in the original, right?

Comment: @jxh Yeah, technically yes, I agree.

Comment: @vsoftco: _"Those are local object allocated on the stack"_ You have absolutely no idea whatsoever where they allocated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right, I know about the storage duration etc. Just wanted to say that you don't need `delete` actually. Unfortunately I cannot edit my initial comment.

Comment: @agmcleod `objects.clear()` will do what you're trying to do with the loop and `pop_back`

Comment: Thanks for the `objects.clear()` advice :). As far as what was in Ball & Paddle, that's a fair point. My question was more pertaining to property life time. But if you'd like to see: https://github.com/agmcleod/pongclone/blob/master/MyPongClone/Ball.h & https://github.com/agmcleod/pongclone/blob/master/MyPongClone/Paddle.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no leaks here because the memory is not dynamically allocated.